# left join excludes nulls and takes left value

Tags: sql, join, null

```
SELECT p.ticket AS posted, 
       e.ticket AS settled, 
       Sum(e.amount) 
FROM   post AS p 
       LEFT JOIN settle AS e 
              ON p.ticket = e.ticket 
WHERE  p.date = '2016-05-10 00:00:00.000' 
GROUP  BY p.pticket, 
          e.eticket 
ORDER  BY posted
```

I understand that the grouping or **where** is the culprit but I've tried so many variations, the rows for the two tables are :
(Table1=Table2)
(**total** = (item + tax= **total**))

So the second table has 2 rows that I sum. I need the date because it has to much info and I've tried "is null" in dates and in other places but can't get this right. Instead of null, it shows the value of the left table as if they match.

Comment: Can you show us some table structure along with expected and observed output?  You probably want to be doing something like `COALESECE(sum(e.AMOUNT), 0)`, but without data it is hard to say for certain.

Comment: cleaned up code, grammar, tags

Comment: show your current output, and expected output. Data sample would be nice too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out! Just love this site and wanted to leave input for whoever runs into this, please correct me if my information is not accurate as I would like to explain in detail but basically, from what I understand and from SQL Fundamentals, nulls are considered outer rows and therefore I would need a "Left **Outer** Join":

```
   SELECT p.ticket AS posted, 
           e.ticket AS settled, 
           Sum(e.amount) 
   FROM   post AS p 
          LEFT JOIN settle AS e 
          ON p.ticket = e.ticket 
   WHERE  p.date = '2016-05-10 00:00:00.000' 
   GROUP  BY p.pticket, 
          e.eticket 
   ORDER  BY posted
```

A good rule that stood out for me and helps me check my joins with nulls is that the `Where` clause should only have conditions to the table where the nulls will not be included, so you keep the outer rows, with the exception of "is null". You could use that with a column on the non-preserved table and still get nulls.

Comment: The word "Outer" is optional.  it should cause no change in behavior.  As to where clause yes, if you want to limit the results of the table on the right of a left join, and keep the nulls, then yes, you need to put the limiting critiera as an AND on the ON Clause so... `on p.ticket = e.ticket and e.attribute = 'value' WHERE p.date = Date`

Comment: Thanks!, yea  i originally read that too, that outer was optional, will retry, but when i started reading on outer rows, it seemed to make sense a little more, will try and replicate when i get a chance but the thought process in my answer has helped me, thanks again!